# Is there an easier way to know in Java if a rejected task (by an Executor) has been run as "CallerRunsPolicy"?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, executor

I am using Spring and I have setup a `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` (to run similar and repetitive tasks frequently) with `CallerRunsPolicy`. Because of the nature of the functionality that I am building, I can have a lot of tasks that get generated and need to be run asynchronously.

Because the queue has crossed its capacity, these tasks get run in the caller's thread. I need a way to find which tasks are run in `Caller's` thread. I know, at runtime, I can invoke methods on the executor to figure out if the queue is full and then any new task will follow `CallersRunPolicy`, but I was wondering if there is any other way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Define your own `RejectedExecutionHandler` and pass it in below constructor.

```
ThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize, long 
keepAliveTime, TimeUnit unit, BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue, 
ThreadFactory threadFactory, RejectedExecutionHandler handler)
```

Sample code for  `MyRejectedExecutionHandler`

```
public class MyRejectedExecutionHandler extends CallerRunsPolicy{
    public void rejectedExecution(Runnable r, ThreadPoolExecutor executor) {
        // Add your code to log Runnable details.
        super.rejectedExecution(r, executor);
    }

}
```

Comment: Makes sense. I did not realize there was a method on the executor to register rejection callback. Thanks anyways !